# Set Focus on DataGridViewCombobox while pressing arrow key up and down

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridviewcombobox

I have a datagridview in which there are three columns .actually this is a dataprocessing application thats why i want use of keyboard(minimal use of mouse)
the code  is as follows 
[code languge="csharp"]

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable odt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn odc = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn odcSec = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn odcThird = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn odcForth = new DataColumn();
            odc.ColumnName = "Class";
            odt.Columns.Add(odc);
            odcSec.ColumnName = "Subject Name";
            odt.Columns.Add(odcSec);
            odcThird.ColumnName = "Grade";
            odt.Columns.Add(odcThird);
            odcForth.ColumnName = "GradeCollection";
            odt.Columns.Add(odcForth);
            DataRow odr = odt.NewRow();
            odr["Class"] = "FYBA";
            odr["Subject Name"] = "Hindi";
            odr["Grade"] = "A";
            odr["GradeCollection"] = "A,B,C,D,E";
            odt.Rows.Add(odr);
            DataRow odrFirst = odt.NewRow();
            odrFirst["Class"] = "SYBA";
            odrFirst["Subject Name"] = "English";
            odrFirst["Grade"] = "B";
            odrFirst["GradeCollection"] = "A,B,C,D,E";
            odt.Rows.Add(odrFirst);
            DataRow odrSecond = odt.NewRow();
            odrSecond["Class"] = "SYBA";
            odrSecond["Subject Name"] = "English";
            odrSecond["Grade"] = "C";
            odrSecond["GradeCollection"] = "A,B,C,D,E";
            odt.Rows.Add(odrSecond);
            DataRow odrThird = odt.NewRow();
            odrThird["Class"] = "TYBA";
            odrThird["Subject Name"] = "Marathi";
            odrThird["Grade"] = "D";
            odrThird["GradeCollection"] = "A,B,C,D,E";
            odt.Rows.Add(odrThird);
            DataRow odrForth = odt.NewRow();
            odrForth["Class"] = "FYBA";
            odrForth["Subject Name"] = "Telagu";
            odrForth["Grade"] = "E";
            odrForth["GradeCollection"] = "A,B,C,D,E";
            odt.Rows.Add(odrForth);
            if (odt != null && odt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtClass = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            txtClass.HeaderText = "Class";
            txtClass.MaxInputLength = 20;
            txtClass.Width = 70;
            txtClass.Name = "Class";
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns.Add(txtClass);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtSubjectName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            txtSubjectName.HeaderText = "SubjectName";
            txtSubjectName.MaxInputLength = 20;
            txtSubjectName.Width = 70;
            txtSubjectName.Name = "SubjectName";           
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns.Add(txtSubjectName);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            comboboxColumn.HeaderText = "Grade";
            comboboxColumn.DropDownWidth = 160;
            comboboxColumn.Width = 90;
            comboboxColumn.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
            comboboxColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;              
            kryptonDataGridView1.TabStop = true;
            kryptonDataGridView1.Focus();
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, comboboxColumn);
            for (int i = 0; i < odt.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                string[] row1 = new string[] { odt.Rows[i]["Class"].ToString(), odt.Rows[i]["Subject Name"].ToString() };
                kryptonDataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
                string sItemNames = odt.Rows[i]["GradeCollection"].ToString();                  
                char[] charArray = new char[] { ',' };
                string[] sItemNameArray = sItemNames.Split(charArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);                  
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");               
                dt.Columns.Add(dc1);              
                DataRow odrinner = dt.NewRow();
                odrinner["Name"] = "--Select--";
                dt.Rows.Add(odrinner);
                foreach (string item in sItemNameArray)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(item);
                }
                comboboxColumn.DataSource = dt;
                comboboxColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";                    
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(odt.Rows[i]["Grade"].ToString()))
                {
                    kryptonDataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = odt.Rows[i]["Grade"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    comboboxColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "--Select--";
                }
            }
        }                       
    }
```

[/code]

Now i want to use arrow key as well as enter key for combobox selection but when i press arrow keys then the focus goes to next row combobox column ,it is not selected that particular combo box.In the same when i use enter key then the focus goes to next column.I want when i hit enter key or arrow key then it select combobox(means focus shuld be on combobox) so that i can select items from that combo box without space hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
    private void kryptonDataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, 
                                                DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            kryptonDataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
```